# How can I set margin for div inside column div in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I set margin for div inside column div in bootstrap, like in the code I am trying to make margin 5px but it doesnt work!

```
<div class="container bg_red">          
        <h1>Test DIV boxes</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 thin_border bg_green">
                <div class="bg_blue">
                Some content here for panel 1       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 thin_border">
                Some content here for panel 2
            </div>
        </div>                      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? Check the `margin-5` class that is added to one div and not the other so you can see the difference.

```css
.thin_border {
  border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
}
.margin-5{
  margin: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container bg_red">
  <h1>Test DIV boxes</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 thin_border bg_green">
      <div class="bg_blue margin-5">
        Some content here for panel 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 thin_border">
      Some content here for panel 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```